# Rearrange journal year and pages for biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, journal

I want to switch the field year and pages for the journal entry, so the field year is always last.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @article{laumer2016,
    title = {Optical Analysis of Polymer Powder Materials for {{Selective Laser Sintering}}},
    author = {Laumer, T. and Stichel, T. and Nagulin, K. and Schmidt, M.},
    date = {2016},
    journaltitle = {Polymer Testing},
    volume = {56},
    pages = {207--213},
    langid = {english}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-numeric]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}
\renewcommand{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\volnumdelim}{\addcomma\space}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
    \autocite{laumer2016}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible ways to do that and which is best for you depends on what exactly you expect when your `.bib` entry features additional fields (e.g. `note`, `doi`, ...).

The following is not too long and gives reasonable output

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-numeric]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}
\renewcommand{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\volnumdelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\jourvoldelim}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\jourserdelim}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\servoldelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde. “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19, 4, pp. 377–395, 1998. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Note that this is specific to the `@article` entry type. If you want to move year and pages for `@inbook` or `@incollection` a different approach is needed.

Comment: Thanks! How would I go about doing the same for a @incollection?

Comment: @Johannes Depends on the details of the desired result. In general I would say redefine the bibmacro `chapter+pages` to do nothing and print `chapter` and `pages` in the bibmacro `publisher+location+date` (which in `biblatex-ext` is defined via `pubinstorg+location+date`). If you'd like a hand with that, I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: I would really appreciate it! I've posted a new question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538718/rearrange-incollection-year-and-pages-for-biblatex